# Unit test exception in VS2015 Community

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I created a new unit test project in VS 2015 Community, created a simple test method:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;

int c = a + b;
```

Then when I right click this test in the Test Explorer and select 'Debug Selected Test' I get the following exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred Message: Exception thrown:
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll Additional
>   information: Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly
>   'file:///C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration.resources.dll'
>   ou uma de suas dependências. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo
>   especificado.

The dll file is there, but there's not .resources.dll file in that path.

Does anyone know why is it happening or how to solve it? I could just ignore, but the console is getting very messy with many of this exception being thrown.

Comment: Have you tried repairing your installation? Looks to me as if something is missing in the installation folder.

Comment: Did you add a test project? Does the test class and methods have proper [TestClass] and [TestsMethod] attributes? How are you running the tests?  Bottom line it looks like 1) You don't have a tests project, 2) A Test Class and 3) A test method.  Plus the code example you've shown shows us nothing other than C# code.

Comment: @JohnPeters Yes, it's a Unit Test Project, with both [TestClass] and [TestMethods]... I guess I'll try to reinstall everything then...

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same thing.

Comment: @ChrisNevill I had to completely uninstal VS and reinstall from zero. Just repairing the installation didn't solve the problem...

Comment: Thanks that's what I ended up doing too!  Gotta love Microsoft stuff sometimes!

Answer (score 3):

I put the 3 code rows written in a test method in an empty project and it runs with Passed result and with no exception so the problem is not in code but in your Setup

If there is not that file in that path I think you already get the point :-)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem after running my tests a few times. I even tried running empty test methods, but the exception kept getting thrown. Creating a new solution and adding the existing projects worked for me.